# How does type reflection for implicit types work?

Tags: go, reflection

From what I've understood, Go is statically typed and doesn't normally do implicit type conversions. So constants declared without an explicit type get based on what's required when they are first used.

So in the following snippet, I'd expect `n` to be a `float64`, since that's what `math.Sin` expects. But when printing out the reflected type, I see an `int`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    const n = 5000 // No explict type

        // fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(n)) // this would print "int"

    fmt.Println(math.Sin(n)) // math.Sin expects a float64

    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(n)) // print "int"
}
```

What's actually happening here? Does `n` actually have an implict int type? Or does reflection not show the actual type cases like this? I don't think `math.Sin` is typecasting it's argument since the compiler throws an error if I specify an explicit type.

Comment: When you pass an (untyped) constant to a function such as `math.Sin()`, a type (`float64`) is given and `5000` can be represented by `float64` precicely, so it will be converted to `float64`. If you pass it to `reflect.TypeOf()` or `fmt.Println()`, no type info is available so the integer constant `5000` will be converted to its default type (`int`). See [The Go Blog: Constants](https://go.dev/blog/constants). _"... an untyped constant has a default type, an implicit type that it transfers to a value if a type is needed where none is provided."_

Comment: Constants and variables are two _different_ things in Go and typing rules for constants are different from that of variables and probably _very_ different from what other languages do with constants. See https://go.dev/ref/spec#Constants and https://go.dev/blog/constants. And of course https://go.dev/tour/basics/15 ff.

Comment: Note that this has _nothing_ to do with reflection at all. Your use of package reflect just makes understanding constants more difficult as now an untyped constant `n` gets assigned to a function parameter of type `interface{}`.

Comment: @Volker my bad, I meant constants. Thanks for the blog posts. From what I see now, Go's constants are more akin to C's `#define`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Untyped constants get typed] based on what's required when they are first used.

This is where you're misunderstanding. A type is selected for every use independently.

math.Sin requires a float64 argument, so the compiler must select float64 here.

reflect.TypeOf takes an interface{} argument, so the compiler is free to choose any of the numeric types (because they all implement the empty interface). Here it chose the default integer type: int.